# dc.LineTo not drawing on OnPaint() unless I move the use the mouse and move the window out of view?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

Unless I make  "static CPaintDC dc(this);" the line won't draw?  But this is not good as it will eventually error, also the graphics wont' keep on the screen.

Not sure what I am doing wrong

Note:  I have a Timer that calls to this every 100ms(x and y are incremented)
thx

```
void CGraphicsDlg::OnPaint() 
{
    CString s;
    CPaintDC dc(this);// device context for painting

    if (IsIconic())
    {
        SendMessage(WM_ICONERASEBKGND, (WPARAM) dc.GetSafeHdc(), 0);

        // Center icon in client rectangle
        int cxIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXICON);
        int cyIcon = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYICON);
        CRect rect;
        GetClientRect(&rect);
        int x = (rect.Width() - cxIcon + 1) / 2;
        int y = (rect.Height() - cyIcon + 1) / 2;

        // Draw the icon
        dc.DrawIcon(x, y, m_hIcon);
    }
    else if(x==0)
    {
        s.Format("%d", x);
        edXa->SetWindowText(s);

        dc.MoveTo(20,400);
    }
    else if (x>0){
        s.Format("%d", x);
        edXb->SetWindowText(s);

        dc.LineTo(20 + x, 40);  // doesn't draw unless I make "static CPaintDC dc(this);" <- which will error out 
    }
    CDialog::OnPaint();
}

void CGraphicsDlg::OnTimer(UINT nIDEvent)
{
    if(nIDEvent==1){
        srand( (unsigned)time( NULL ) );

        //y = rand() % 100;
        y++;
        x++;

        OnPaint();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LineTo` draws a line from one point to another, using the selected pen. You need to use `MoveTo` to define the start of the line, and you need to select a pen into the DC.

The larger problem is how you're trying to use the DC. It isn't meant to be permanent; you're supposed to acquire it, draw everything to it, then shut it down. When you try to make `CPaintDC` static, Windows will eventually shut it down and every attempt to use it thereafter will return an error.

The proper way is to save any coordinates that you need for *all* of the drawing you need to do. Use a combination of `MoveTo` and `LineTo` to draw individual line segments, and every time you reenter OnPaint you need to start over.

Comment: I do that when x==0 condition is met... you can see in the code

Comment: @jdl, create a CPen object and use `dc.SelectObject` to select it. You have code to do a `MoveTo`, but you need to do both at the same time. The `MoveTo` will be lost the next time OnPaint is called.

Comment: I am trying to draw a plot that constantly updates every 100ms.  Unless I make "static CPaintDC dc(this);" it won't do that but just the once. But this is not good to do as the app will error when I try and close out.  Also the graphics disappear if a hide the window and display it again.  thx

Comment: From the OnTimer function I called OnPaint().  That was the problem I needed to do:  CRect rect;
  GetClientRect(&rect);
this->InvalidateRect(rect, true);  

Using the "pens" has helped... thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not answering your question, but have you noticed that **CDialog::OnPaint()** will be called even if **IsIconic()** returns **TRUE** ?

I think you will need to use an extra pair of **{}** to solve this ;-)